# GRUB dual boot won't load after using Windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

So I have Ubuntu 14.04 in my laptop installed with a dual boot of Windows 7. One day I used Windows and installed some big programs (Maya and Unity), the next day after starting the computer, the BIOS screen showed up as usual, but then it said "GRUB Loading..." and then the computer restarted. I can start BIOS, so I can change the boot order if needed, but I can't enter either Windows or Ubuntu.

My guess is I have to fix GRUB, as it seems most of the problems with dual boot come from a damaged GRUB, but I'm not sure if it has any other problem with the files in Windows and Ubuntu.

EDIT: Here is my BootInfo Summary Report: http://pastebin.com/PBtdn5Wf

Comment: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: I do not know burg. I would just use Boot-Repairs Advanced total uninstall/reinstall of grub. Make sure Internet is working. Burg has not been maintained for years so may not always work or work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the Ubuntu live CD or USB.
Please start your computer with it.
Then install Boot Repair (please issue the below commands)

sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

Then start the application and re-install GRUB

[image: Screenshot of the application]

Then restart your computer and everything should be back to normal